# llamar imagenes a una consulta de php

Tags: php, sql, ajax

**buenas noches como lo mencione en el titulo no encuentro el codigo, para llamar a  mi formulario de consulta una imagen, cargada en mi base de datos, los codigos que digite me salen errores, si me pudieran orientar se los agradecería, les dejo parte de lo que he hecho de mi formulario de consulta, lo llame buscar. Php

```
***<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "especies forestales";
    $conn = new msqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
      $check = @getimagesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);
  
    $salida = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM reconocimiento especies WHERE nombre_comun LIKE '' ORDER By id_arbol LIMIT 25";
    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reconocimiento_especies WHERE id_arbol LIKE '%$q%' OR nombre_comun LIKE '%$q%' OR nombre_cientifico LIKE '%$q%' OR tallo_raiz LIKE '%$q%' OR hoja LIKE '%$q%'OR img LIKE '%$q%'OR imaginex_hoja LIKE '%$q%'OR usos LIKE '$q' ";
    }
    $resultado = $conn->query($query);
    if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
        $salida.="<table border=1 class='tabla_datos'>
                <thead>
                    <tr id='arbol'>
                        <td>nombre_comun</td>
                        <td>nombre_cientifico</td>
                        <td>tallo_raiz</td>
                        <td>hoja</td>
                        <td>usos</td>
                        <td>img</td>
                        <td>imaginex_hoja</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
        <tbody>";
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['nombre_comun']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['nombre_cientifico']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['tallo_raiz']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['hoja']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['usos']."</td>
                        </tr>";
        }
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }else{
        $salida.="AUN NO HAZ DIGITADO NADA :(";
    }
    echo $salida;
    $conn->close();
?>*****
```

Comment: Puedes guardar la URL de la imagen en la base de datos, además te sugiero que uses [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) ya que MySQL está deprecado.

Comment: En el manual de php dice: **Advertencia Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL.** ¿Qué versión de php usas? Si es inferior a 5.5 (muy vieja) Debes mostrar algunos de los errores que comentas

Comment: buenas noches gracias por los comentarios no soy programador hasta ahora estoy leyendo practicando y tratando de aprender de expertos como ustedes, estoy usando msqli  estoy usando una version nueva es una tabla dinamica, ya cree el formulario de insertar modificar y eliminar datos con imagenes, pero he visto que hay personas que tienen sus formularios de consulta con imagenes y asi pense realizar mi consulta, por eso solicite la ayuda de expertos como ustedes de antemano gracias sus consejos seran bien reicibidos y si orientarian bien

Comment: ¿De casualidad estas viendo el curso de PHP impartido por píldoras informáticas? Segundo, ¿En cual de esos campos es donde guardas tu imagen o, en cual de ellos esta destinado para guardarla?

Comment: gracias edgar por la respuesta, todo lo que mencionas ya lo tengo registrado en un formulario a mi bd, pero lo que estoy creando ahora es la consulta, este formulario que les deje es el que me llama los datos de texto  que ya tengo registrado en bd lo unico que me falta en este formulario de consulta es que me aparezcan las fotos o imágenes  en este formulario, como les dije hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo si me pudieran colaborar

Answer (score 0):

No se como tengas creado tu formulario pero puedo echarte una mano. Para ello crearemos un simple formulario. Donde obtendremos dos cosas: El nombre de la foto y la imagen.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
  <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo">

  <input type="submit" value="Subir foto!">
</form>
```

La siguiente parte es la divertida, aquí vamos a desarrollar como puedes "subir la imagen". En este caso, vamos a guardar en la base de datos la ruta donde esta la imagen. Así no cargamos de más la base de datos y la mantenemos optima: Pasos a seguir:

- Abrir tu conexión
- Verificar que, lo que envían en el formulario no este vacío y, que esta sea una imagen
- Si comprobamos que hay una imagen enviada, ubicarle al programa en que carpeta se va a guardar, guardarla en un arreglo y usar un método de PHP para colocarla en donde deseas.
- Crear su respectiva query para la base de datos
- Imagen guardada

Abrimos la conexión, usemos tu configuración para esto:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "especies forestales";
$conn = new msqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Conexión fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

//Verificar lo que se envía en el formulario sea una imagen o un "file" y que esta no este vacia
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
  //con la funcion getimagesize nos retorna un arreglo de propiedades de la imagen, si no es una imagen, retorna falso
  $check = @getimagesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);
  
  //Si la funcion no te devuelve un false (si hay imagen dentro), ubicarle donde guardar  la imagen, esto usando las propiedades de php
  $carpeta_destino = 'tuCarpeta/';
  $archivo_subido = $carpeta_destino .$_FILES['foto']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);

  //Ejecutamos la consulta para guardar esto en la base de datos
  $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tuTabla (titulo, imagen) VALUES (:titulo, :imagen)");
  $statement->execute(array(':titulo' => $_POST['titulo'], ':imagen'=> $_FILES['foto']['name'] ));

  //Esto es opcional pero, puedes hacer una redireccion a tu pagina principal, en este caso, un index
  header("Location: index.php");

//En caso de que esto falle, puedes enviar un mensaje de error
} else {
  echo "El archivo es muy pesado o no se pudo ejecutar la acción";
}
```

Espero esto te pueda ayudar, sino puedes preguntar y con gusto te ayudo.

Comment: hola buenas noches edgar trate de combinar mi codigo que ya tenia con el que tu me hicieste el favor de enviarme  y sigue sin aparecerme las imagenes, donde te lo puedo enviar para que me lo puedas corregir y gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, el código que acabas de publicar, agrégalo en la pregunta, es decir, edita tu pregunta agregando este código para que pueda replicarla en mi pc.

Comment: hola edgar intente hacerlo pero me aparece No se pudo enviar tu edición. Consulta el error que se indica más arriba. que es bastante codigo que escriba mas explicaciones lo hago y no me deja enviar que pena el abuso de confianza pero este es mi correo jeremygumo@gmail.com por si me envias un mail para poderte escribir mejor muchas gracias de antemano me ayudarias bastante